# Multiple criteria in CASE STATEMENT SQL - ZIpcode issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to find address issues/inconsistencies in our work data. One of the issues I am coming across is zipcode errors. I basically want a report showing potential address errors.

I have written several working case statements, but here is the issue I am coming across:

```
CASE 
    WHEN e.city = 'FRESNO' AND e.zip LIKE '936%' 
        THEN 'FIX' 
        ELSE '' 
END AS Zip_Error.
```

This criteria works, however I realized that there is one zipcode in Fresno that has a '936' and that is '93650'.

I have tried several different methods to solve this but its not working. Because my case statement says all '936%' its saying they all need to be fixed. I am not sure how to write it to exclude '93650 since that is correct.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks so much.

```
CASE 
    WHEN e.city = 'FRESNO' AND e.zip LIKE '936%' 
        THEN 'FIX' 
        ELSE '' 
END AS Zip_Error.
CASE 
    WHEN e.city = 'FRESNO' AND e.zip LIKE '936%' AND NOT IN '93650 
        THEN 'FIX' 
        ELSE '' 
END AS Zip_Error.
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a case statement in SQL, its a case expression (as the tag explains).

Comment: why not just add `AND e.zip <> '93650'`

Comment: `AND NOT IN '93650'` for which column? Perhaps if you try `AND e.zip NOT IN ('93650')`?

Comment: Thank you. This works, Unfortunately, not for what I am doing. When I apply AND e.zip NOT IN ('93650') it cuts all the addresses with this zipcode. What I am looking for is a column that says "FIX" or ' '. With the case expression I currently have in my sql, its saying "FIX" for every address with '93650' as well as any other address that starts with '936%' I want the column to show "Fix" for zipcodes that have everything starting with '936' with the exception of '93650' because 93650 is a correct Fresno zipcode. I hope I am making sense. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the e.zip <> '93650' and unfortunately the data is not populating the way I need it to.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] we can't keep guessing as to what your data looks like and why its not working. Provide sample data and desired results in your question, add a DBFiddle demonstrating the issue. And correct your question to say "case expression".

Comment: Your `AND NOT IN '93650 then 'FIX'` is not valid sql syntax. You are missing a single quote, and, you don't have your zip in parens. Just change to what siggemannen suggested way above. And you need to have this first if you have multiple expressions using 936*, which I doubt you should.

Comment: With corrections noted, both versions work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think you are misinterpreting the suggestions above and putting the `and e.zip <> '93650'` in the wrong place. You need that in the case expression, not in your where clause.

```
CASE 
 WHEN e.city = 'FRESNO' and e.zip LIKE '936%' and e.zip <> '93650' THEN 'Fix' ELSE 'ok' 
END AS Zip_Error
```

Comment: Yes! This worked! CASE 
 WHEN e.city = 'FRESNO' and e.zip LIKE '936%' and e.zip <> '93650' THEN 'Fix' ELSE 'ok' 
END AS Zip_Error. Thank you so much!! I am still learning SQL and fairly new. I appreciate your thoughtfulness and patience in answering my question

Answer (score 0):

As the first matching condition is applied in a `CASE` statement, you can check the (valid) FRESNO/93650 combination before the more general ones:

```
CASE 
    WHEN e.city = 'FRESNO' AND e.zip = '93650' 
        THEN '' /* this combination is valid */
    WHEN e.city = 'FRESNO' AND e.zip LIKE '936%' 
        THEN 'FIX' /* Other 936... zips are invalid */
    ELSE '' 
END AS Zip_Error
```